# Bulk USB device connection and programming

Tags: windows, usb, usb-drive, industrial

Some background on my issue, my company sells single-use short life battery powered USB devices that certain customers require a certain 'profile' config programmed into the device before shipping. We currently sell them in batches up to 2000. Each one is plugged into a computer(Windows) with our configuration software running, the device is auto detected and then notified when completed. Takes roughly 10-15 seconds per USB device. No input is required on the computer besides inserting the device.

As you can imagine this is a very slow process that is increasing in frequency. The device shows up as mass storage device with about 100kb of storage. All devices have the same name when showing in My Computer. The issue is the programming software does not detect if multiple devices are plugged in, only loading the profile onto the first device plugged in.

Looking for a possible suggestion/solution to improve the speed of configuring these devices? My scratch pad idea was to buy 10-20 port USB hubs and possibly look at enabling one port in sequence every 20 seconds either with hardware buttons or software setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with your programming software, but since the devices present themselves as USB Mass Storage devices, you might be able to plug a bunch of them in at once, then use a script to dismount them all and mount only one device at at time. A one technique to do that is to use the `mountvol` command.

To unmount a drive

```
mountvol  [DriveLetter] /p
```

To mount a drive

```
mountvol  [DriveLetter]
```

Source:
https://superuser.com/questions/704870/mount-and-dismount-hard-drive-through-a-script-software

Another option would be to bypass the programming software entirely. You could use the programming software once to figure out what it is doing to the device (I would guess it's just copying some config file onto the drive). Once you know what it's doing, write your own script that can handle many devices in parallel.